# Добавение Маркер Label-а

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Всем доброго дня!Добавляю на карту маркеры с лэбэлами от 0 до 9 проблем нету ...

делаю это таким образом

```
    var labels = '0123456789';
    var labelIndex = 0;

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
    map: map
  });
}
```

Щас появилась нужда сделать их до 30-ти.Я попробовал добавить но он не читает по 2 циры ... А ве также добавляет по одной

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Естественно. Операция целочисленного деления возвращает позицию символа в labels.

Напишите так

```
label: (labelindex++).toString() ,
```

Comment: Нет это не помогло

Comment: Вы сделали преобразование в стринг но всеравно он незнает что 12 это не 1 а 2 .

Comment: а можноли по массиву прогнать???

Comment: Я исправил ответ

Comment: ахахахахаха.)))))))Ты взял отбросил labels;а сразу начел инкрементить labelindex и преобразоввать его знаение в стринг?)))))))))

Comment: Умноооо однако .век живи век учись ))))

Comment: само собой. твой пример кода как раз и выводит метки от 0 до 9, если нужно до 10 меток. Я его трансформировал, чтобы работало с любым числом. Либо тебе вообще не это нужно, тогда приведи здесь полный фрагмент работающего кода.

Comment: не не мне как раз это и надо было )чтоб каждому маркеру добавлялась цифра )